# Default Messaging App version 4.2.1 is not able show in intent chooser dialog with other apps like whatsapp, etc

Tags: android, messaging

I want to show only Messaging app and Whatsapp application in Intentchooser. The following code is working fine with some other devices like moto e, g, etc.. But in some other devices its now showing the default messaging application.  This is my code. Please help me.

```
private void shareTheApp() {
    Resources resources = getResources();

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
    emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
    List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
        // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
        ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
        String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        if (packageName.contains("com.whatsapp")) {
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_text));
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        }
        if (packageName.contains("mms")) {
            isMmsAvailable = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            if (packageName.contains("mms")) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_text));
            }
            intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
        }
    }

    if(!isMmsAvailable) {
        isMmsAvailable = false;
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", resources.getString(R.string.share_text));
        intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(smsIntent, "", "Messaging", R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    }

    // convert intentList to array
    LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray(new LabeledIntent[intentList.size()]);
    Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.openchooser_tittle));
    openInChooser.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);
    startActivity(openInChooser);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I solved this problem :) below the code.

```
  Resources resources = getResources();
    List<Intent> selectedIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfos=getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    if(!resInfos.isEmpty()){
        for(ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos) {
            String packageName=resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if(packageName.contains("com.whatsapp")){
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_text));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
                selectedIntents.add(intent);
            }
        }

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) {
            // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
            ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);
            String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (packageName.contains("mms")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                if (packageName.contains("mms")) {
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, resources.getString(R.string.share_text));
                    selectedIntents.add(intent);
                }
            }
        }

        if(!selectedIntents.isEmpty()){
            Intent chooserIntent = null;
            chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(selectedIntents.get(0), resources.getString(R.string.openchooser_tittle));

            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, selectedIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    }
```

we need to call both action ACTION_SEND and ACTION_VIEW.  Now it will show in intent chooser for both type of messaging app. Hope it might be usefull for some else.

Comment: does it show you the options or automatically take you to the app ?